# In kernel 3.8, how the first user process is switched into user mode while kernel_execve is removed

Tags: linux-kernel

In kernel 3.8.x and later version, the definition for run_init_process is changed.

The following is the new definition for run_init_proces in kernel 3.8.

```
 static int run_init_process(const char *init_filename) {
         argv_init[0] = init_filename;
        return do_execve(init_filename,
                (const char __user *const __user *)argv_init,
                 (const char __user *const __user *)envp_init); }
```

Compared to the definition in kernel 3.7.x and old version.

```
static int run_init_process(const char *init_filename) {
         argv_init[0] = init_filename;
         return kernel_execve(init_filename, argv_init, envp_init); }
```

The most critical part in **kernel_execve** is that it will call the ret_from_kernel_execve, which will switch into the user mode then.

In the new definition, **kernel_execve** is gone. My question is how the first user process is switched to the user mode then.

Comment: The article [https://lwn.net/Articles/520227/] (Al Viro's new execve/kernel_thread design) is very helpful. The major change is located at the *copy_thread*

Comment: A more [current URL](https://lwn.net/Articles/520227/).

Comment: @artlessnoise: actually, he just needs to learn to use `<>` around his URLs instead of `[]` ...

Answer (score 1):

The successful `do_execv()` sets up the `current` process to run the new program (e.g. via [`load_elf_binary()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c?v=3.8#L561)), and then returns 0 to `run_init_process()`, which returns 0 to `kernel_init()`, which also returns 0, and was called as part of:

```
    kernel_thread(kernel_init, NULL, CLONE_FS | CLONE_SIGHAND);
```

This is where the rules from https://lwn.net/Articles/520227/ come in: our `fn()` has returned 0 after an `execve`, so "the thread will proceed into userland context created by that execve".